# Finding the transformation matrix R

Tags: matrices, transformation

Please help me in solving this problem, I am not sure what a transformation matrix R is and how to proceed.. Any help is appreciated.

Find the transformation matrix R that relates the (orthonormal ) standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^3$ to the orthonormal basis obtained from the following vectors via the Gram Schmidt process:

|*a1*> = $\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
i\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} $
|*a2*> = $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
-i
\end{pmatrix} $
|*a3*> = $\begin{pmatrix}
i\\ 
0\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Well, perhaps they were thinking just about the matrix $\pmatrix{1&0&i\\i&1&0\\0&-i&-1}$? This maps (by multiplication on left) the standard basis of $\Bbb C^3$ to the given column vectors.

Comment: But how does that help me in finding a transformation matrix?? I mean how to find a tranformation matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seem to be asking you to apply the Gram Schmidt process to those three vectors. Do it, that is what the exercise is about. Then (because those initial vectors are linearly independent) you will get three orthonormal vectors. Putting *those* three vectors as successive columns into a matrix will give a unitary matrix$~U$. Depending on the conventions used, your transformation matrix $R$ is either $U$ or its inverse (which is also $U^*$ since $U$ is unitary). In any case a linear operator given by $A$ on the standard basis will be given by $U^{-1}AU$ on the new (result of Gram Schmidt) basis.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed explanation.